# Copy files from one user to another permissions issue

Tags: linux, git, permissions, gitolite

I have a user 'git' that owns a git repository. I'm trying to setup a post-update hook that copies the files in the repository to /var/www/site/. I'm still getting a hang of users and permissions in linux, what is the best scheme for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either have git own `/var/www/site/`, and give it 660 permissions on it (read and write, no execute), or make `/var/www/site/` world writeable (which is not entirely a good idea, as then any user can copy, edit, etc. files in `/var/www/site/`).  [`chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) could help you change the owner, and [`chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) can help you change file permissions.

You can also add git to the group who owns `/var/www/site/`, and make sure that the group has read/write permissions on `/var/www/site/` as well.

And if you ever need help with chown, chmod, or any other linux command, [`man`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/man) can help you out.

Comment: I have rwxrwxr-x permissions on the `site` folder, the user git is in the folders group, but git still can't write to the folder. Does git need to have write access to `/var` and `/var/www`?

Comment: @nathancahill no, I don't believe so; you're sure that git is in the same group that owns the site folder, as well as everything in it?

Comment: Logged out and logged in again, everything worked. Thanks a lot.